# How to change color in Vue-Plyr?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-plyr

In [this git issue](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/issues/662) it is discussed how to change the color of `vue-plyr` user interface. **Sampotts** mentions a way by changing `css variables`. I've been trying to do that without success.

In the `node_modules/plyr/src/sass/settings` directory there is a `colors.scss` file but changes to the color variables do not seem to affect player color:

```
:root {
  --plyr-color-main: yellow;
}

$plyr-color-main: var(--plyr-color-main, hsl(198, 100%, 50%)) !default;
$plyr-video-background: var(--plyr-video-background, rgba(0,0,0,1)) !default;
```